# Arrays and method addcar

Tags: java, arrays, methods

im practicing for an exam and have a problem while programming one of the methods
its an addcar method and i dont know how to deal with this method.

the description of addcar: this method will add a Car to the list but first you need to check if the id
is not already entered to add. If the id is already in the array you should print
“Cannot add this car because the id is already in the list”. If it is not possible
to add the Car because the array is full, you should print an error message
“ERROR ADDING LIST IS FULL”.

the code is bellow, starting from the class Car to the class CarDealer(where addcar method should be added to). the conditions should be correct in addcar method but i dont know how to use the variables in the parameters.

```
    public class Car {
        private int id;
        private String model;
        private int year;
        private double price;
        public Car() {
         id = 0;
         model = null;
         year = 0;
         price = 0;
        }
        public Car(int id, String model, int year, double price) {
             this.id = id;
             this.model = model;
             this.year = year;
             this.price = price;
        }
     public int getId() {
      return id;
     }
     public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
     }
     public String getModel() {
      return model;
     }
     public void setModel(String model) {
      this.model = model;
     }
     public int getYear() {
      return year;
     }
     public void setYear(int year) {
      this.year = year;
     }
     public double getPrice() {
      return price;
     }
     public void setPrice(double price) {
      this.price = price;
     }
    }
    public class CarDealer {
        private Car[] Cars;
        private int nCars;
        public final static int MAXSIZE = 100;``

        public CarDealer() {
         Cars = new Car[MAXSIZE];
         nCars = 0;
        }
        public int getnCars() {
         return nCars;
        }
        public int findcar(int id) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i<nCars; i++) {
         if(id == Cars[i].getId()) {
          return i;
         }
        }
        return -1;
        }
        public void addCars(int id, String model, int year, double price) {
         if(nCars < MAXSIZE) {
         for(int i = 0; i<nCars; i++) {
             if(id == Cars[i].getId()) {
              System.out.println("The car is already added");
             }
        }}
         else 
          System.out.println("ERROR: ADDING LIST IS FULL");
        }}
```

Comment: I dont see an increment of nCars. Are you doing it somewhere?

Comment: nope, i didnt write it because i was confused with the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic, please go through the comments to understand

```
public void addCars(int id, String model, int year, double price) {
    if(nCars < MAXSIZE) { // check if the number of cars is less than MaxSize to add
        for(int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++) { // go through the all the cars in the list
            if(Cars[i] != null) { // check if the car in this index is not empty
                if(id == Cars[i].getId()) { // check the id of the car is the same in the list
                    System.out.println("The car is already added"); // print already added if so
                    break; // break since you found a duplicate (an existing car id)
                }
            }else { // you come to this logic because the Car object in the index (i) is empty which means there is no car added
                   // since you add car sequentially in the car list then its safe 
                Car carObj = new Car(id, model, year, price);
                Cars[i] = carObj; // set the car object
                nCars++;  // increment the current car size 
                System.out.println("Added");
                break; // break since you have added the car to the list and no need to go through the for loop
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("ERROR: ADDING LIST IS FULL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done several mistakes but this rewritten method should fix :

```
public void addCars(int id, String model, int year, double price) {
    if(nCars < MAXSIZE - 1) {
        boolean free = true;
        for(int i = 0; i<nCars; i++) {
            if(id == Cars[i].getId()) {
                System.out.println("The car is already added");
                free = false;
            }
        }
        Cars[i] = new Car(id, model, year, price))
    }
    else  System.out.println("ERROR: ADDING LIST IS FULL");
}
```

Comment: it's better if you add comments to your answer, explaining what you've changed and why, instead of some solution for him to copy paste